# Disable player falling

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make it so that in Minecraft, whenever a player falls, they have a fall speed of 0, stopping them from falling.
Can I do that in vanilla, and if not is there any way to do it with plugins?

Comment: Does that basically mean there is no gravity?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: if you do so, bruh 1 jump is gonna take you to the moon unless you have a roof

Comment: I honestly don't care about that.

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable in Vanilla Minecraft, without the usage of any game modifications, using a bug with the levitation effect:

Run `/effect give <player> minecraft:levitation 1000000 255 true`. You can restore gravity by running `/effect clear <player> minecraft:leviation`.

Unfortunately, this means you cannot jump at all, but it has quite an interesting effect, and movement works like a slower version of Creative Mode flight:

[image: Floating Player]

Comment: Sadly, I want to do this by potion, and the effect doesn't work properly.

Comment: You can get a potion using `/give @p minecraft:potion{Potion:"minecraft:water",CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:25,Amplifier:255,Duration:1000000}],display:{Name:"\"No Gravity\""}}`. Unfortunately, while this disables gravity, it also prevents any upwards velocity. If you would like upwards velocity, try using different amplifiers, slow falling and/or jump boost.